# ¿Como asignar acciones a cada opción en un AutoCompleteTextview?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un AutoCompleteText como el siguiente:

```
public static String [] opciones = {
        "Opcion 1", "Opcion 2", "Opcion 3"
};

final AutoCompleteTextView camposugerencias = findViewById(R.id.input_search);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dropdown_item_line, opciones);

    camposugerencias.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo asignar una acción a cada opción que esta en el public static String opciones

Ejemplo.

Para la opción 1 que se cambie la visibilidad de un elemento CardView.
Para la opción 2 que se cambie a otra activity.
Para la opción 3 que se cambie el color del fondo de la activity.
Espero puedan Ayudarme

Comment: La verdad es que no se si se puede hacer. Lo que sí puedes hacer es un Adapter personalizado para tu `AutoCompleteTextView`, con tu propio layout, y ahí, en la función `getView`, obtienes el `TextView` y tal vez te deje ponerle un listener para hacer algo. Habría que probarlo. Tienes un ejemplo [aquí](https://www.zoftino.com/android-autocompletetextview-custom-layout-and-adapter). Suerte!

Comment: ya lo resolvi bro gracias de cualquier modo

Answer (score 1):

```
camposugerencias.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String opcionsolicitada = camposugerencias.getText().toString();

            if (opcionsolicitada.contentEquals("Metro Observatorio")){

              //Tu acciones///

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente cargas tu array `opciones` en el Adapter

```
  final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dropdown_item_line, opciones);
```

ahora puedes usar dos opciones

User el listener `OnTouchListener`

```
camposugerencias.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(view instanceof AutoCompleteTextView){
                    AutoCompleteTextView parentView = (AutoCompleteTextView)view;

                    // Obtiene la entrada especificada en el AutoCompleteTextView.
                    String textoElemento = parentView.getText().toString();

                 }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Usar el listener `OnItemClickListener`

```
camposugerencias.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Obtiene la entrada especificada en el AutoCompleteTextView.
        String textoElemento = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
});
```